How to assess and analyze different clinical symptoms at the same time in R
I am currently working on a study, in which we aim to compare the post-surgical complications of patients who underwent a specific type of brain surgery. In one of our analyses, we would like to compare the symptoms our patients (using the Createtableone function) experienced after the brain surgery.
The problem we are facing is that we collected the symptoms in different categorical variables. Each patient could have a maximum of four different symptoms, but some had fewer than four. We categorized the symptoms as FND (focal neurological deficit), resulting in four variables: FNDtype, FNDtype2, FNDtype3, and FNDtype4. Now, I would like to combine these variables into one, so that I can perform a descriptive analysis showing the frequency of each symptom for each stratified group.
Here are the relevant parts of the Rscript:
# Postcraniectomia Infection
data$postcraniotomy_infection <- factor(data$`Postcraniotomy infection (y=1, n=0)`, levels = c(0,1), labels = c("no", "yes"))

# FND Type 
data$FNDtype <- factor(data$`Type of FND (1)`, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), labels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", "aphasia", "visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", "cranial nerve dysfunction", "neglect","dysarthria","other"))

# FND Type 2 
data$FNDtype2 <- factor(data$`Type of FND (2)`, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), labels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", "aphasia", "visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", "cranial nerve dysfunction", "neglect","dysarthria","other"))
                        
# FND Type 3 
data$FNDtype3 <- factor(data$`Type of FND (3)`, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), labels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", "aphasia", "visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", "cranial nerve dysfunction", "neglect","dysarthria","other"))
                       
# FND Type 4 
data$FNDtype4 <- factor(data$`Type of FND (4)`, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), labels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", "aphasia", "visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", "cranial nerve dysfunction", "neglect","dysarthria","other"))

# Trying to merge FND Types into one variable
data$fndtype <- paste(data$FNDtype, data$FNDtype2, data$FNDtype3, data$FNDtype4, sep = ",") 

vars <- c("fndtype")

table <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, data = data, strata = c("primary_infection"), testNonNormal = kruskal.test, addOverall = TRUE)

kableone(table, nonnormal = vars)

Here is the dput dataset, including the stratifying variable postcraniotomy_infection and the four different symptoms our patients experienced:
list(postcraniotomy_infection = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("no", 
"yes"), class = "factor"), FNDtype = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L), levels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", 
"aphasia", "visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", 
"cranial nerve dysfunction", "neglect", "dysarthria", "other"
), class = "factor"), FNDtype2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 
1L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
1L), levels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", "aphasia", 
"visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", "cranial nerve dysfunction", 
"neglect", "dysarthria", "other"), class = "factor"), FNDtype3 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", 
"aphasia", "visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", 
"cranial nerve dysfunction", "neglect", "dysarthria", "other"
), class = "factor"), FNDtype4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), levels = c("none", "hemiparesis", "hypoesthesia", "aphasia", 
"visual field defects", "coordiantion disturbance", "cranial nerve dysfunction", 
"neglect", "dysarthria", "other"), class = "factor"))

I tried to use the paste() function with the argument sep=",", which indeed created a single variable with the different values separated by a comma. However, when I tried to create the descriptive analysis with CreateTableOne, the results showed me the statistics about the symptom combinations (e.g., hemiparesis, hypesthesia, coordination disturbance n=xx) rather than the statistics about the single symptoms (e.g., hemiparesis n=XX, hypesthesia n=XX, coordination disturbance n=XX).
I am really hoping that someone in the SO community can help me, as I strongly believe there must be a solution to this problem. Let me know if you need additional information!
Thank you in advance for your support.
Best regards, Massimo

You can mitigate the problem with different categorical variables. For each symptom we create a new column starting with all zeros. We then check each patient to see if they had this symptom in any of their four FND entries. If they did, mark them with a 1 for this symptom.
Finally we create a df where row is a different symptom. The columns show how often each symptom occurred in patients with/without infection.
#install.packages("tableone")
library(tableone)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)        

clean_data <- function(data) {
  # Ensure input is a data frame
  df <- as.data.frame(data)
  
  # Get all unique symptoms (excluding "none")
  all_symptoms <- unique(c(df$FNDtype, df$FNDtype2, df$FNDtype3, df$FNDtype4))
  all_symptoms <- setdiff(all_symptoms, "none") # Remove "none"
  
  # Initialize transformed data frame
  transformed_data <- df %>%
    select(postcraniotomy_infection) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) # Ensure postcraniotomy_infection is character
  
  # Add binary columns for each symptom
  for (symptom in all_symptoms) {
    transformed_data[[symptom]] <- 0 # Initialize with zeros
    
    # Check presence across all FNDtype columns
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      if (symptom %in% c(df$FNDtype[i], df$FNDtype2[i], df$FNDtype3[i], df$FNDtype4[i])) {
        transformed_data[i, symptom] <- 1
      }
    }
  }
  
  # Add a 'none' column
  transformed_data <- transformed_data %>%
    mutate(none = if_else(rowSums(select(., all_symptoms)) == 0, 1, 0)) # Row sums of all symptoms
  # Validate symptom columns: keep only those with at least one '1'
  valid_cols <- colSums(transformed_data[c(all_symptoms, "none")]) > 0
  valid_symptoms <- names(valid_cols)[valid_cols]
  
  # Create table comparing symptoms between infection groups
  table <- CreateTableOne(
    vars = valid_symptoms, 
    data = transformed_data, 
    strata = "postcraniotomy_infection",
    addOverall = TRUE,
    test = TRUE
  )
  
  return(list(table = table, transformed_data = transformed_data))
}
# use it

vars <- c("fndtype")
Onetable <- clean_data(data)
transformed_data <- Onetable[["transformed_data"]]

# sumamrize the data!
summary_data <- transformed_data %>%
  group_by(postcraniotomy_infection) %>% # Ensure column exists and is spelled correctly
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ sum(.), .names = "total_{.col}"), .groups = "drop") %>% # Summarize all columns
  mutate(across(starts_with("total_"), ~ round(. / nrow(transformed_data), 2), .names = "avg_{.col}")) # Add averages

summary_data


# plot OneTable
kableone(Onetable[["table"]], nonnormal = vars)

Output




Overall
no
yes
p
test




n
84
37
47




hemiparesis (mean (SD))
0.26 (0.44)
0.41 (0.50)
0.15 (0.36)
0.008



neglect (mean (SD))
0.11 (0.31)
0.19 (0.40)
0.04 (0.20)
0.031



aphasia (mean (SD))
0.13 (0.34)
0.19 (0.40)
0.09 (0.28)
0.164



hypoesthesia (mean (SD))
0.18 (0.39)
0.22 (0.42)
0.15 (0.36)
0.430



dysarthria (mean (SD))
0.07 (0.26)
0.14 (0.35)
0.02 (0.15)
0.045



cranial nerve dysfunction (mean (SD))
0.07 (0.26)
0.08 (0.28)
0.06 (0.25)
0.764



visual field defects (mean (SD))
0.07 (0.26)
0.11 (0.31)
0.04 (0.20)
0.252



other (mean (SD))
0.07 (0.26)
0.16 (0.37)
0.00 (0.00)
0.004



coordiantion disturbance (mean (SD))
0.12 (0.33)
0.11 (0.31)
0.13 (0.34)
0.787



none (mean (SD))
0.42 (0.50)
0.19 (0.40)
0.60 (0.50)
<0.001




About the table
This table summarizes the occurrence of various symptoms between patients with and without post-craniotomy infections. The columns represent:

Overall: The average occurrence of each symptom across all participants.
No: The average occurrence for patients without an infection.
Yes: The average occurrence for patients with an  infection.
p: The p-value from statistical testing, indicating the
significance of differences between the groups.

Analysis
Significant Findings (p < 0.05)

Hemiparesis:
Occurs more frequently in the "No infection" group (41%) compared to
the "Yes infection" group (15%). p-value = 0.008 indicates a
statistically significant difference. Suggests hemiparesis is less
common in patients with infections.
Neglect: Occurs more frequently in the "No infection" group (19%)
compared to the "Yes infection" group (4%). p-value = 0.031 indicates
a statistically significant difference. Suggests neglect is less
common in patients with infections.
Dysarthria: More common in the "No infection" group (14%) than in the "Yes infection" group (2%).
p-value = 0.045 shows a statistically significant difference.
Suggests dysarthria is less common in infected patients.
Other Symptoms: Found in 16% of the "No infection" group but absent in the "Yes infection" group.
p-value = 0.004, showing strong statistical significance.
Suggests other symptoms are highly unlikely in patients with infections.
None: The "No infection" group reported "None" less frequently (19%) compared to the "Yes infection" group (60%).
p-value < 0.001, highly significant.
Indicates that patients with infections are more likely to report no symptoms.

Non-Significant Findings (p ≥ 0.05)
Interpretation
Symptoms more common in the "No infection" group: Hemiparesis, neglect, dysarthria, and "other symptoms." These findings suggest that these symptoms may be protective markers or unrelated to infection.
"None" as a symptom: Patients with infections are significantly more likely to report no symptoms.
Non-significant differences: Aphasia, hypoesthesia, cranial nerve dysfunction, visual field defects, and coordination disturbances show no meaningful difference between groups.

Thank you so much for your answer!
This helps a lot! However, could you help me interpret these results? Am I right that, for instance, a mean of 0.26 for hemiparesis means that 26% of the 84 patients showed a hemiparesis?
The p-values are absolutely needed! Thank you very much!
As a next step, if I would like to perform a multivariate analysis, how should I continue with the transformation of the variables?

@MassimoBarbagallo Each symptom is recorded as a binary variable (1 = present, 0 = absent). The mean value for each symptom across the groups reflects its prevalence. A mean of 1.00 indicates the symptom is present in all patients of that group, while a mean of 0.00 means it is absent in all patients. I added my interpretation. I also added summary_data which shows the total numbers of each symptom per group as well as the average.

For continuing to multivariate MVKSA Book.
